# (Angular) how to render the component template that extends from another

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 components, MyComponent and BaseComponent. MyComponent extends BaseComponent, I need to render the BaseComponent template in MyComponent.

I tried it this way

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  template: `
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></ng-container>
  `,
})
export class MyComponent extends BaseComponent{
  
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-base',
  template: `
      <ng-template #template>
        <div>Hello World</div>
      </ng-template>
`
})
export class BaseComponent {
  @ViewChild('template') template!: TemplateRef<any>;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use parent template inheritance in angular, because it using component model with one template per component.

You can use nested component with `<ng-template #base>` definition, `<router-outlet>`, `<ng-content>`, or use directive for pass to the template component instance.